# How to retrieve all items from a list (with custom fields) by javascript object model

Tags: list, javascript, client-object-model, splistitem

I need to get all my custom fields from my list by **Javascript Object Model**..

The code I wrote down is this:

```
var items;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[name=ItemChildCount]").text("Figli");
         var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Codice Ragione Sociale');
         var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
         items = list.getItems(camlQuery, 'Ragione Sociale');

         context.load(items);

        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataFailed));  
    });

    function onListDataSucceeded(sender, args) {

        var listItemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();


        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

            alert(oListItem.get_item('Title') + oListItem.get_item('Ragione Sociale'));
        }

    }

    function onListDataFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('List Data fetch failed. ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

When I arrive on `oListItem.get_Item('Ragione Sociale')` system told me the column is not loaded... But I told the system to load it on getItems!

Comment: Did you try Internal Name? :)

Comment: eirikb's comment is likely the issue. You can determine the field's internal name by going to the properties page for the list, right clicking on the field, selecting properties and in the URL all the way at the end you will see Field=InternalName. Just remember that underscore is encoded in the URL as %5F so Field=Link%5Fx0020%5Fto%5Fx0020%5FTemplate is Field=Link_x0020_to_x0020_Template. See here:  http://www.isurinder.com/blog/post/2011/06/01/SharePoint-Internal-Column-Names.aspx

Comment: A post on this subject [Good SharePoint JavaScript Client Object model use example for beginners][1] [1]:http://www.sharepointbreak.com/2013/07/22/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-and-jquery-calendar-events-carousel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you specify Include as part of the query string that is passed to the load(clientObject) method in order to specify which properties to return. The following example uses this approach to return only the title and ID of each list in the collection.

```
 clientContext.load(collList, 'Include(Title, Id)');
```

**If  solution not work then please remove space in field name that may problem.**

See this msdn post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185009.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I use the Include and removed the space! Everything works fine ;)

Comment: Noteworthy that it requires the internal name. So for a column 'Due Date' it would most likely look like this: `Include(Due_x0020_Date)`.